# Avoiding temporary table in explain plan

Tags: mysql

I want to avoid the `temporary table` in the explain plan of this query:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/544dd/1

```
EXPLAIN SELECT count( p2m.product_id ) AS total, p2m.merchant_id
FROM merchants_to_products p2m
LEFT JOIN products p ON p2m.id = p2m.product_id
GROUP BY p2m.merchant_id
ORDER BY total DESC

| ID | SELECT_TYPE | TABLE |  TYPE | POSSIBLE_KEYS |        KEY | KEY_LEN |    REF | ROWS |                                        EXTRA |
|----|-------------|-------|-------|---------------|------------|---------|--------|------|----------------------------------------------|
|  1 |      SIMPLE |   p2m | index |        (null) | product_id |       8 | (null) |   11 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 |      SIMPLE |     p | index |        (null) |    PRIMARY |       4 | (null) |   10 |                                  Using index |
```

Comment: What temporary table?

Comment: @Shaeldon: I presume he is referring to the `Using temporary` in the first row of the explain results.

Comment: Which is the original tables and which is temp?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: "p2m.id = p2m.product_id"  Surely some mistake

Comment: true. should be p.id. sorry

Comment: And the answer is simple. Remove the ORDER BY clause

Comment: Thanks Strawberry that worked. but is there a way to still order the query result and avoiding the temporary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-temporary-tables.html)

> `Using temporary` will appear  when there is an ORDER BY clause and a
>   different GROUP BY clause, or if the ORDER BY or GROUP BY contains
>   columns from tables other than the first table in the join queue, a
>   temporary table is created.

In your posted query if you remove the `order by` altogether (OR) use same column `p2m.merchant_id` in both `group by` and `order by`; it will no more use internal temporary table

```
EXPLAIN SELECT count( p2m.product_id ) AS total, 
p2m.merchant_id
FROM merchants_to_products p2m
LEFT JOIN products p ON p2m.id = p.id
GROUP BY p2m.merchant_id
ORDER BY p2m.merchant_id DESC
```

See your modified [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/544dd/13)

Comment: but this would order by p2m.merchant_id and I need order by total.

Comment: @Christoph, `order by total` or `order by count(merchent_id)` was the culprit for `using temporary`.